# Add Id column in a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Rails app, where one of the models does not have the `id` column. Doing some research I found the migration that created it:

```
create_table(:the_model, :id => false) do |t|
  # columns
end
```

Now, on a new migration, I want to add the `id` column in a Rails standard way (not using database specific sql). How can I do that?

I already tried this without success:

```
change_table(:the_model, :id => true) do |t|
end
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can either manually add the id column:

```
add_column :table_name, :id, :primary_key
```

or clear (or backup) your data, rollback to this migration, get rid of the option `:id => false`, and re-migrate.

Comment: The command worked! Although I ended up recreating the table (`drop_table` and `create_table` in the migration) because it already had a primary key. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By running the migration will the id column of the existing records automatically get populated with unique id values? If not, how/what do I assign them to keep the system happy?

Comment: When you tell rails to make the column :primary_key, it sets up the database in such a way that the db will automatically populate the id field for you. All your records will magically gain unique ids.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to mention `:integer`

`rails g migration add_id_to_model id:primary_key` worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You already got your answer, but here is a one liner that does all in this case

```
rails generate migration AddIdToModel id:integer
```

Look at the syntax of migration file name Add*ColumnName*To*TableName* followed the column description.
It will generate something like below

```
class AddIdToModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :models, :id, :integer
  end
end
```

Now you can change this line if you feel for anything else. and just run `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: `rails g migration add_id_to_model id:primary_key` doing all for you

Comment: This adds the ID as a regular integer, rather than a primary key of the table

Comment: This option does not makes unique the column and does not apply autoincrement