# Rails 4.0 integer ID -> UUID / Add options hash to table in ActiveRecord Migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uuid, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-4

stackoverflow newbie here, although I've been on here many times to look for helpful answers in the past.  This is my first question though, so please be nice :)

I've been trying to figure out how to change a table in an ActiveRecord Migration in Rails by adding (or modifying) the options hash that comes with the create_table command.  More specifically, I'm trying to convert a model that uses integer IDs into one that uses UUIDs in Rails 4.0 and postgresql 9.1.9.

So for example, my schema currently looks like this:

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.timestamps
end
```

and I want to create a migration to change it to this (following the UUID guide [here](http://labria.github.io/2013/04/28/rails-4-postgres-uuid-pk-guide/)):

```
create_table :users, id: false do |t|
  t.primary_key :id, :uuid, :default => 'uuid_generate_v1()'
  t.string :name
  t.timestamps
end
```

I can add/drop/change columns, but I can't figure out how to put the `id: false` into the table.  So far the only way I've come up with is to completely nuke the table via `drop_table :users` and then re-create it, which seems mighty inefficient to me.  Is there some ActiveRecord method I can invoke to add an options hash?  Tried to google it with no success, but maybe I don't know what the right search query is?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Edited: grammar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed!  Discovered that passing in `id: false` simply means the id column is not generated in the database, so calling `remove_column :users, :id` would drop the column and add `id: false` to the schema.

Key insight came from the following older thread: [Add Id column in a migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548746/add-id-column-in-a-migration)

For completeness, the full migration file:

```
def up
  remove_column :users, :id
  add_column :users, :id, :uuid, default: 'uuid_generate_v1()'
end
def down
  remove_column :users, :id
  add_column :users, :id, :primary_key
end
```

Comment: The green-field way to do this is `id: :uuid` http://labria.github.io/2013/04/28/rails-4-postgres-uuid-pk-guide/